# Auto layout not ignoring UITabBar in tvOS

Tags: tvos

I have constrained one of my UIViews to the top of the main UIViewController view, and I would expect that the "top" of the main superview would not change if the tab bar is open. However, that is not the case. When the View Controller loads, the top of the view I constrained is the bottom of the Tab Bar. The view does not move with the UITabBar, rather stays a fixed distance from the top of the screen, leaving space for the tab bar to occupy. Is this the intended behavior, and if so, is there a workaround (to have the view extend under the tab bar)?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing and it's especially problematic because if the view is reloaded upon dismissing a subsequent view, the layout is reset as you would expect (i.e. my controls are flush with the point having disregarded the tab bar so it looks entirely different). Haven't yet found a work-around.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. I posted on the dev forums last week and have not yet received a response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this will solve your problem — seems to have worked for me.

[image]

On the storyboard, select your View Controller and go to the Attributes Inspector. Uncheck `Under Top Bars`. The view will now adjust once you select it in the tab bar.

Comment: Worked for me. I have TabbarController, and a table view with a top constraint to the Top Layout Guide. When "Under Top Bars" is checked, the table view appears under the tabbar. Unchecked, the table moves below the tabbbar as expected.

Comment: This didn't work for me either...  Any other suggestions? FYI: I'm using a collection view with default flow layout.

Comment: If the view controller being added to the tab bar controller is a UINavigationController this will not work. A simple workaround is to create a UIViewController, add the navigation controller to it, then add the view controller to the tab bar controller.  UITabBarController>UIViewController>UINavigationController
You will need to uncheck the Under Top Bars or set edgesForExtendedLayout for the extra view controller being added.